# how to copy files from one server to another without changing its time stamp by using XML?

Tags: xml

```
<target name="CopyModel">
  <delete dir="C:\ASD_DEV\Dep_Model\temp" /> 
  <mkdir dir="C:\ASD_DEV\Dep_Model\temp" /> 
  <ftp action="recv" server="${hostsrc}" remotedir="/usr/data/hqdata/${SrcEnv}/modelsvr/datafiles/model" userid="${usernamesrc}" password="${passwordsrc}" verbose="yes" binary="yes">
    <fileset dir="C:\ASD_DEV\Dep_Model\temp">
      <include name="${ModelName}"/>
    </fileset>
  </ftp>
 <ftp server="${hostdest}" remotedir="/usr/data/hqdata/I4T/modelsvr/datafiles/model" userid="cis1" password="star!fire" verbose="yes" binary="yes">
   <fileset dir="C:\ASD_DEV\Dep_Model\temp">
     <include name="${ModelName}"/>
   </fileset>
 </ftp>
 <sshexec host="${hostdest}" username="${usernamedest}" trust="true" password="${passworddest}" command="cd /hqdata/I4T/modelsvr/lib;./package.sh" /> 
</target>
```

I am trying to copy some files from server1 to new_server, now those files must be as like so that timestamp as it was on sever1 must be here on new_server, but I am not able to do that..
So please help me out

I am basically working on xml and the source and destination servers are on linux.

Comment: By "Batch" to you mean Windows batch files?

Comment: just forget about batch #richard its btch code,

Comment: I just need to know, how can i copy files from one to another server without changing its time stamp..

Comment: suppose the file creation time is mentioned there, i need that same on new one, not the copying time as new timestamp

Comment: here in this segment no use of batch is there

Comment: I just made a batch file to call this xml code..

Comment: We are going to need to know which OSs (source and destination) and File Systems are involved. Please also edit the question down to the question you want (references to FTP etc. appear and unless relevant are just a distraction).